# Express.js jade template layout is not working in few pages

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I created create form using Node, express and jade template. But my create page not use main layout that i will created. i extends the main layout it work on my employee list page but not working on create page. it only show html not css or bootstrap. please help.

Here is my site structure.

[image]

My main.jade:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
   include htmlheader.jade
  body.page-body.hold-transition.skin-blue.sidebar-mini(style='background: #d2d6de')
//- | @section('htmlheader')
//- include layouts/partials/htmlheader.jade
//- | @include('layouts.partials.htmlheader')
// this page specific styles
//- | @show
#fb-root
.page-container
  .main-content.main-header


    include sidebar.jade
    include pageheader.jade
    block content

  // Sample Modal (Default skin)
  include footer.jade
//- | @include('layouts.partials.footer')
// Theme Scripts
```

My route.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var employee = require("../controllers/EmployeeController.js");

// Get all employees
router.get('/', employee.list);

// Get single employee by id
router.get('/show/:id', employee.show);

// Create employee
router.get('/create', employee.create);

// Save employee
router.post('/save', employee.save);

// Edit employee
router.get('/edit/:id', employee.edit);

// Edit update
router.post('/update/:id', employee.update);

// Edit update
router.post('/delete/:id', employee.delete);


module.exports = router;
```

My create.jade:

```
extends ../layout/main

block content
body
.container
  h3
    a(href='/employees') Employee List
    //- a.btn.btn-success(href="/employees")  Employee List
  h1 Create New Employee
  form(action='/employees/save', method='post')
    .form-group
      label(for='name') Name*
      .col-md-10
        input#name.form-control(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Name')
    .form-group
      label(for='address') Address*
      .col-md-10
        input#address.form-control(type='text', name='address', placeholder='Address')
    .form-group
      label(for='position') Position*
      .col-md-10
        input#position.form-control(type='text', name='position', placeholder='Position')
    .form-group
      label(for='salary') Salary*
      .col-md-10
        input#salary.form-control(type='text', name='salary', placeholder='Salary')
    button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Create
```

When i try this http://localhost:3000/employees/create it will show this 
[image]

My index.jade:

```
extends ../layout/main

block content
body
.container
  h3
    a(href='/employees/create') Create Employee
  h1 Employee List
        //-  if employee.length>0
        //-      for(var i=0 i<employee.length i++)
  table.table.table-striped
    thead
      tr
        th Employee Name
        th Position
    tbody
      tr
        //- td
          //- a(href='/employees/show/#{employee[i]._id}') #{employee[i].name}
        td  Moaiz
        //- td #{employee[i].position}
        td Software Developer
  //- div No employees found.
```

And in index.jade i use the same layout and it wil show like this:

[image]

Please help where i can miss something or do something wrong.

**Edit:**

I think issue is this it not pick the right path.
Here is the image:

[image]

When i hit for create employee than the path would start from `employees`. And i cannot find why it includes `employees` in the path. I think thats the problem thats why it cannot show layout properly. Before hit the `create` you seen in an image it does not include `employees` in path. Please help me to find the solution.
Here is my **htmlheader.jade**:

```
head  
 meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
 meta(charset='utf-8')
 meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
 meta(name='description', content='Admin Dashboard')
 meta(name='author', content='')
 meta(property='og:type', content='website')
 meta(property='og:title', content='')
 meta(property='og:description', content='')
 meta(property='og:image', content='')
 // CSRF Token
 meta(name='csrf-token', content='{{ csrf_token() }}')
//- | {{--
//- title {{ config('app.name', 'Admin Dashboard') }}
//- | --}}
title  Admin Dashboard
// Styles
script(src="{{url('dist/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}}")
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic')
//- |     {{-- 
//- link(rel='stylesheet', href="{{url('assets/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css')}}")
//- |  --}}
meta(content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no', name='viewport')
// Bootstrap 3.3.7
link(rel='stylesheet', 
href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
// Font Awesome
link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")
// Ionicons
link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css")
// jvectormap
link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css")
// Theme style
link(rel='stylesheet', href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css")
//
  AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
  folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load.
  link(rel='stylesheet', href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css")
  link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/morris.js/morris.css")
  link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css")
  // Date Picker
  link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css")
  // Daterange picker
  link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css")
  // bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor
  link(rel='stylesheet', href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css")
  // HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries
  //if lt IE 9
  script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js')
  script(src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js')
  block custom_styles
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a jade/pug problem. Your CSS might be the issue here. Do you have absolute or relative paths in your file for static assets ?

Comment: But `main` layout page extend with `index.jade` that works and also `main` is extend in `create.jade` but why one page is working great and other not ? @StephenS

Comment: Can you add the jade file where you define your css stylesheets ?

Comment: I add a template for `Admin panel` and i add all `CSS`, `Bootstrap` file in folder `public` i add all files @StephenS

Comment: I meant the jade file which have the `link` tag for your stylesheets.

Comment: No i think i cannot add any jade file that have link in it. But i add `header.jade` , `footer.jade` and `sidebar.jade` that have links i include these three files in my `main.jade` file. @StephenS

Comment: @StephenS i edit my question if you help me with this issue then please help

Comment: the `htmlheader.jade` file I believe has your CSS declarations. I presume these are relative URL's. I'd like to help, but there is a lack of data to point at something. If you could add the file `htmlheader.jade` or `header.jade`, maybe it would be easier to find the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196049/discussion-between-stephen-s-and-moaiz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using relative url's which depend on your current path. Instead you should set your static assets to absolute url's so that it doesn't change when you navigate to nested url's.

Change this

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")
```

To this

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css")
```

This should be done for all static assets

```
// Ionicons
link(rel='stylesheet', href="/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css")
// jvectormap
link(rel='stylesheet', href="/bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css")
// Theme style
link(rel='stylesheet', href="/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css")
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly open development manager (F12 key) of browser window of your localhost:port.

Go to console tab see the errors.Some css and js files path is missing.

update path as per adminlte js and css files.

like below :

**- header.jade**

```
  title=AdminLTE
meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/adminlte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/adminlte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/adminlte/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css')
```

**- js.jade**

`

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/adminlte/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/adminlte/bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/fontawesome/js/fontawesome.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/adminlte/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/adminlte/dist/js/demo.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/adminlte/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js')
```

`

Now your screen will look as per theme view.